# Intellij Too much memory consumption in Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04, java-memory-leaks

When I open intellij IDE with my spring boot app, I can see too much cpu and memory usage of my system. Facing this problem from last 1-1.5 month. Earlier, it was running smoothly.
I am using the latest intellij version in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I have increased intellij heap size to 6144. But still get hung after running the app for some time.
Below is the resource consumption stats:
[image: resource stats]

Comment: Could you please share logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)?

Comment: @y.bedrov, I can see the log file but where to email the zip file? Didn't find any emailId in the link you provided

Comment: You may use any online sharing service

Comment: @y.bedrov, please check this:  [Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PUbDACdp4sYITNOAvdHSQ3kmfLjxtQ_A/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please try updating to the latest version. Also please try to temporarily disable custom plugins: "Loaded custom plugins: JPA Buddy (2022.3.3-222), Smart Tomcat (3.8.5)"

Comment: My intellij is the latest version(2022.2.1) and those two plugins were disabled. However, I just uninstalled them.

Comment: One more thing, when I run my code, I always see a background task on bottom row: "Computing layout" I don't know why this comes here(was not before it). Can't stop this permanently

Comment: Please try to disable bundled "Diagram" plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297357/Computing-layout-runs-for-a-very-long-time-after-service-is-started-Service-Dashboard-this-loads-CPU-and-sometimes-IDEA-hung-due

Comment: @y.bedrov, thank you very much. I think, disabling "Diagram" plugin helped it. Seems like working fine like previously.  Let's see what happens next